# How to properly unwrap and use nil when i'm receiving <null> from dictionary - swift 3

Tags: ios, null, swift3

I have a struct:

```
    struct SomeTopic {

        var name: String?
        var parent: String?

        mutating func setName(name: String?) {
            self.name = name
        }

        mutating func setParent(parent: String?) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
```

In other class I am trying to access a dictionary topicsList :

```
    class Blabla {

        var topics: Array<SomeTopic>!

        func topicsDidFinishLoading(topicsList: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>) {

             if (self.topics != nil) {
                 self.topics.removeAll()
             }

             for topic in topicsList {

                 print(" Topic: ", topic)
                 var newTopic = SomeTopic()

                 newTopic.setName(name: topic["name"] as? String)
                 newTopic.setParent(parent: topic["parent"] as? String)

                 print("New topic created: ", newTopic)
                 self.topics.append(newTopic)
             }
        }
```

In the last line of the function "self.topics.append(newTopic)" I am getting an error in runtime : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Print statements:

Topic:  ["name": News, "parent": `<null>`]

New topic created:  SomeTopic(name: Optional("News"), parent: nil)

I have tried using:

```
    if let name = topic["name"] {

         newTopic.setName(topic["name"])
    }
```

and all the variations of testing for nil, but it passes into the if-let loop when the content of topic["name"] is `<null>`.

Comment: Your last line is crashing because `self.topics` is `nil`.  Your handling of nulls in the dictionary seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was only in the declaring

```
    var topics: Array<SomeTopic>!
```

instead of

```
    var topics = Array<SomeTopic>()
```

which caused the crash because self.topics were nil.

Comment: And this is why you avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals :) they hide issues like this